# Inline JavaScript onclick function

Tags: javascript, onclick

Is there a way to write following code inline like so?

```
<a href="#" onClick="function(){
    //do something;
    return false;
};return false;"></a>
```

Instead of doing this:

```
 <a href="#" onClick="doSomething(); return false;"></a>

 function doSomething(){
    //do something;
 }
```

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Why? Inline code is horrible and non-maintainable or reusable

Comment: because I am echoing it in the page and I want to keep it constrained. and I dont want to repeat doSomething multiple times.

Comment: @Toniq Why would you have to repeat `doSomething` multiple times? Declare it once. If you need to associate certain data with the `<a>`, use a `data-*` attribute and render information there. And don't set the `onclick` in the tag - wait for the DOM to be ready, get all `<a>` elements, and bind a click handler to each, calling `doSomething` and passing it the `data-*` attribute you may need.

Comment: @Toniq - Whatever you're trying to do, put the code in a function and call that function in your `onclick` handler.  Writing more than a single command or two in inline HTML is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, it's possible (if you fix the syntax errors), but not practical.

Comment: Why aren't you using .js files for your javascript code?

Comment: This makes sense for a quick test script (sometimes).

Answer (score 131):

You can use Self-Executing Anonymous Functions. This code will work:

```html
<a href="#" onClick="(function(){
    alert('Hey i am calling');
    return false;
})();return false;">click here</a>
```

Comment: Upvoting this but... really, I hope you have a good reason you're writing inline code, it's usually bad practice.

Comment: ^^ I can see it being bad practice when repeating code, but anonymous functions do have their place. I wrote a function that calls a custom boostrap confirm modal. I want it to handle a situation on cancel and confirm uniquely for that instance when I need it. It's silly to write the two functions elsewhere and have to search for them within the code when they're not reused.

Comment: My use case for this is for dismissing a loading splash screen. The onclick deletes the splash screen from the DOM.

Comment: @JaredMenard try to replace anchor tag with div.

Comment: I just used this method to insert a shim for debugging into a page I don't control, so I couldn't add an extra function. It's ugly, but it works

Answer (score 35):

This should work:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="function hi(){alert('Hi!')};hi()">click</a>
```

You may inline any JavaScript inside the `onclick` as if you were assigning the method through JavaScript. I think is just a matter of making code cleaner keeping your js inside a script block

Answer (score 15):

Based on the answer that @Mukund Kumar gave here's a version that passes the event argument to the anonymous function:

```
<a href="#" onClick="(function(e){
    console.log(e);
    alert('Hey i am calling');
    return false;
})(arguments[0]);return false;">click here</a>
```

Answer (score 12):

This isn't really recommended, but you can do it all inline like so:

```
<a href="#" onClick="function test(){ /* Do something */  } test(); return false;"></a>
```

But I can't think of any situations off hand where this would be better than writing the function somewhere else and invoking it `onClick`.

Comment: I tried this and in firefox I get: SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Comment: would this test function be heard outside of href scope?

Comment: I thought it'd exist in the global scope, but that doesn't seem to be true. _As far as I can tell_ it won't exist outside the scope of that tag, but I'm not sure what scope it exists in for sure.

Comment: I found the solution helpful, indeed. Having a bunch of websites. Simply copying the whole html line without worrying about browser caching as the links already have gone out to the client…Nice and dirty.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but I was looking for a solution to this today. When you're "inlining" JavaScript like below, don't include "function xx()" and such. See the below example. I tested it today, and it works perfectly without console errors or warnings.

Wanted to share a solution:

```
<a href="#" type="button" onClick="var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDIV'); if (myDiv.style.display === 'block') { myDiv.style.display = 'none'; } else { myDiv.style.display = 'block'; }">click</a>
```

In a standard HTML markup, the following would be a typical implementation of the "inlined JS" example above.

```
<body>
<a href="#" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</a>
...(this is where the rest of the html page content goes)....
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
     x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```